# My question has to do with the fstring in this code. Why does it print the curly braces when I run the program?

Tags: python

My question has to do with the f-string in this code. Why does it print the curly braces when I run the program?

> ### Instructions:
>
> Think of something you could store in a `list`. For example, you could make a list of mountains, rivers, countries, clients, languages, or anything else you'd like. Write a program that creates a `list` containing these items and then uses each function introduced in this chapter at least once.

```
fav_vgames = ["call of Duty BO I", "call of Duty BO II", "call of Duty BO MW", "forza horizon"]

print(fav_vgames)
print(len(fav_vgames))

#Accessing a random element
print(fav_vgames[2])
print(fav_vgames[-1])

#Using an f-string
fav_vg = fav_vgames.pop(2)
print(f"My favorite videogame of all time is: ", {fav_vgames[0].title()})
```

Comment: Why did you put the curly braces in the command to begin with? You're constructing a set.

Comment: Ah. My book has it surrounded by curly braces so I did the same. I am still in the beginning stages of learning how to code so I was struggling for a while. It worked when I removed them! Thank you!

Comment: The curly braces go *in the f-string*.

Comment: You were trying to do `print(f"My favorite videogame of all time is: {fav_vgames[0].title()})")` - this is just a typo, voting to close as such.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try the following two simpler examples: `x = 1; print(f"one", {x})` and `x = 1; print(f"one {x}")`. Do you see the difference in the code? Do you see how that relates to the different output? Next: let's check if your book is any good, and if you are properly learning from it. In your own words: what is a *function*? How does calling a function work? What is a *parameter*, and an *argument*? How does the `print` function handle the arguments that are passed to it?

Answer (score 2):

[`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) format text and expressions with `{}` braces **within** the quotes. You're after:

```py
print(f"My favourite video game of all time is: {fav_vgames[0].title()}")
```

> [PEP for f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)

---

The reason it was printing the braces was because `{fav_vgames[0].title()}` was turned into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set).

Using `print()` with multiple arguments will just print both arguments separated by a space:

```py
>>> print(1, {1})
1 {1}

# Type of a plain {} without an f-string
>>> print(type({1}))
<class 'set'>
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

> ```
> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
> ```
>
> All **non-keyword arguments** are converted to strings like `str()` does and written to the stream, separated by `sep` and followed by `end`. Both `sep` and `end` must be strings; they can also be `None`, which means to use the default values. If no objects are given, `print()` will just write `end`.

Which means:

```py
print(f"My favourite video game of all time is: ", fav_vgames[0].title())
```

Is also valid for your use case